# Set up URI or catalog resolver with Saxon/XQuery

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I am developing a simple command line application in Java to mine data from a large XML data set (15,000+ XML files). I have chosen to use Saxon S9API as the XQuery processor for this. Everything works fine so long as there is open access to the internet where the parser used by Saxon can resolve the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation URI (or any other I will assume).

I have scoured Stackoverflow, as well as general Google searching, for answers on how to provide a catalog to the XQuery processor. I have not found a good explanation on how to do so.

This is the simple code I have at this point, which as I stated works fine when there is open access the Internet:

```java
    package ipd.part.info.mining.app;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
    import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.DOMDestination;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryCompiler;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryEvaluator;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryExecutable;
    import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmAtomicValue;
    import net.sf.saxon.lib.*;
    import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE;
    import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA;
    import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver;
    import org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;

    /**
     *
     * @author tfurst
     */
    public class IPDPartInfoMiningApp {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        private static String ietmPath;
        private static String outputPath;

        private static CatalogResolver resolver;
        private static org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver xres;
        private static ErrorHandler eHandler;

        private static DocumentBuilderFactory DBF;
        private static DocumentBuilder DB;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            initDb();
            try {
                // TODO code application logic here
                System.out.println("Enter path to complete IETM Export:");
                ietmPath = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter path to save report:");
                outputPath = scanner.nextLine();

                Processor proc = new Processor(true);

                XQueryCompiler comp = proc.newXQueryCompiler();

                //File xq = fixXquery(new File(XQ));
                //XQueryExecutable exp = comp.compile(xq);
                XQueryExecutable exp = comp.compile("declare variable $path external;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "let $coll := collection(concat($path,'?select=*.xml'))//itemSequenceNumber \n" +
    "\n" +
    "return\n" +
    "<parts>\n" +
    "{\n" +
    "    for $mod in $coll\n" +
    "    let $pn := normalize-space($mod/partNumber)\n" +
    "    let $nomen := $mod/partIdentSegment[1]/descrForPart\n" +
    "    let $smr := $mod/locationRcmdSegment/locationRcmd/sourceMaintRecoverability\n" +
    "    order by $pn\n" +
    "    return <part pn=\"{$pn}\" nomen=\"{$nomen}\" smr=\"{$smr}\"/>\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "</parts>");
                //Serializer out = proc.newSerializer(System.out);

                Document dom = DB.newDocument();

                XQueryEvaluator ev = exp.load();
                ev.setExternalVariable(new QName("path"), new XdmAtomicValue(new File(ietmPath).toPath().toUri().toString().substring(0, new File(ietmPath).toPath().toUri().toString().lastIndexOf("/"))));
                ev.run(new DOMDestination(dom));

                TransformerFactoryImpl tfact = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

                Transformer trans = tfact.newTransformer();
                DOMSource src = new DOMSource(dom);
                StreamResult res = new StreamResult(new File(outputPath + File.separator + "output.xml"));
                trans.transform(src, res);


            } catch (SaxonApiException | TransformerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IPDPartInfoMiningApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        private static XMLCatalogResolver createXMLCatalogResolver(CatalogResolver resolver)
        {
            int i = 0;

            List files = resolver.getCatalog().getCatalogManager().getCatalogFiles();
            String[] catalogs = new String[files.size()];
            XMLCatalogResolver xcr = new XMLCatalogResolver();

            for(Object file : files)
            {
                catalogs[i] = new File(file.toString()).getAbsolutePath();
            }

            xcr.setCatalogList(catalogs);
            return xcr;
        }

        private static void initDb()
        {
            try 
            {
                resolver = new CatalogResolver();
                eHandler = new DocumentErrorHandler();
                xres = createXMLCatalogResolver(resolver);
                DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DBF.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
                DBF.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
                DB.setEntityResolver(xres);
                DB.setErrorHandler(eHandler);
            } 
            catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

I am receiving this error when I disconnect my machine from the network:

```
C:\Users\tfurst\Desktop\XQuery Test\testXml\test\tool>java -jar IPD_Part_Info_Mining_App.jar
Enter path to complete IETM Export:
C:\Users\tfurst\Desktop\Wire Repl Testing
Enter path to save report:
C:\Users\tfurst\Desktop\Wire Repl Testing\report
Error on line 6 column 2
  collection(): failed to parse XML file
  file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: Read timed out
Aug 20, 2019 2:55:23 PM ipd.part.info.mining.app.IPDPartInfoMiningApp main
SEVERE: null
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: collection(): failed to parse XML file file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: Read timed out
        at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryEvaluator.run(XQueryEvaluator.java:372)
        at ipd.part.info.mining.app.IPDPartInfoMiningApp.main(IPDPartInfoMiningApp.java:80)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: collection(): failed to parse XML file file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/Users/tfurst/Desktop/Wire%20Repl%20Testing/DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml: Read timed out
        at net.sf.saxon.resource.XmlResource.getItem(XmlResource.java:113)
        at net.sf.saxon.functions.CollectionFn$2.mapItem(CollectionFn.java:246)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ItemMappingIterator.next(ItemMappingIterator.java:113)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ItemMappingIterator.next(ItemMappingIterator.java:108)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ItemMappingIterator.next(ItemMappingIterator.java:108)
        at net.sf.saxon.om.FocusTrackingIterator.next(FocusTrackingIterator.java:85)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.ContextMappingIterator.next(ContextMappingIterator.java:59)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentOrderIterator.<init>(DocumentOrderIterator.java:47)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.DocumentSorter.iterate(DocumentSorter.java:230)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.flwor.ForClausePush.processTuple(ForClausePush.java:34)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.flwor.FLWORExpression.process(FLWORExpression.java:841)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:337)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:284)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:151)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryExpression.run(XQueryExpression.java:411)
        at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryEvaluator.run(XQueryEvaluator.java:370)
        ... 1 more


C:\Users\tfurst\Desktop\XQuery Test\testXml\test\tool>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am sure this is probably a relatively simple fix, most likely something I have overlooked. I know how to handle this when working with XSL tranformations, by supplying a catalog and the location of the schemas. Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated.

Comment: It always helps if you give details of the version and edition of Saxon you use. Does that file DMC-HH60W-A-52-21-0001-04AAA-520A-B.xml reference any external resources?

Comment: Yes, I should have given the version, my apologies. I am using 9.9. That file references a few external resources:

xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-2/xml_schema_flat/proced.xsd"

As well as an external entity: <!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0/ent/ISOEntities">

Comment: Is that schema aware XQuery with Saxon EE? I wonder whether other editions would make the parser read/follow the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` at all. I think, for the schema references setting http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#SCHEMA_URI_RESOLVER with http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#setConfigurationProperty-net.sf.saxon.lib.Feature-T- should be possible.

Comment: This is Saxon HE. I will go look into the two links you have provided and see what I can learn from that.

Comment: For the DTDs, I think setting http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#ENTITY_RESOLVER_CLASS to the relevant catalog resolver from org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver should do. On the other hand, all that `Processor` level stuff is not specific to XSLT nor XQuery while you say you have an approach for XSLT.

Comment: The approach I have used in the past for XSLT was not using the S9API, rather the Saxon JAXP implementation. (net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.setURIResolver())

Comment: I set the processor config property as setConfigurationProperty(FeatureKeys.ENTITY_RESOLVER_CLASS, "org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver"). No change. I am unsure how to set the schema resolver.

Comment: There is also http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/Feature.html#COLLECTION_URI_RESOLVER_CLASS but I guess you will have to wait until Michael Kay gives a more insight.

Comment: Thank you for your time this morning (at least its morning here). Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an XML catalog file something like the following in your code should work:

> ```
>         Processor proc = new Processor(false); //false for Saxon-HE
>         XQueryCompiler compiler = proc.newXQueryCompiler();
>         XmlCatalogResolver.setCatalog("path/catalog.xml", proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration(), false);
>         ...
> ```